# Singleton instance does not contain set properties

Tags: c#, wpf, singleton

**Update:
Vote to close this please, my mistake where I was assigning the Authorisation I wasn't assigning it to the instance.**

I'm having an issue with the following code, basically I have two classes which are singletons within, they are declared at the top of my "MainWindow":

```
   public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
    {
public Auth AuthInfo = Auth.GetInstance();
public api myApi = api.GetInstance();
```

The line that sets it a bit further down within the MainWindow class, if I debug this after the assignment the Authorisation string is set.

```
 AuthInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Auth>(responseString);
```

The class declarations are as follows:

Auth

```
   public class Auth
{

   private static Auth instance = new Auth();

   private Auth(){}

   public static Auth GetInstance()
   {
     return instance;
   }
    public string Authorisation { get; set; }
}
```

api

```
   public class api
{

   private static api instance = new api();

   Auth AuthInfo = Auth.GetInstance();

   private api(){}

   public static api GetInstance()
   {
     return instance;
   }
    // other code goes here
}
```

The problem is when I try and access the Authorisation property of the Auth instance from within the api class it's not set? It's almost like GetInstance returns the instance without any properties?

From within the MainWindow class the authorisation property is correct

Comment: Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem - and ideally fix the formatting and follow .NET naming conventions, too... (It's not clear where you're setting any properties, and you don't have an `Authorisation` property in `api`...)

Comment: Thats because Authorisation doesn't exist in the API class it's in the Auth classs which you can clearly see.

Comment: Oh, yes, I see now - your question isn't very clearly worded. But you haven't shown anything that's meant to be setting the property, so how are you expecting it to be set? Again, please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: You never assign to `Authorisation` in this example, so it being `null` is hardly surprising. Please extend your example to exhibit the problem.

Comment: Yeah sorry guys it's 100% set by the login function which is very long, you'll have to take my word for it but i've debugged within the MainWindow class and it gets set and kept fine

Comment: Ah hold on where i'm assigning AuthInfo the JSON data I'm just adding a property rather than assigning the current one no?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class Auth
{

    private static Auth instance = new Auth();

    private Auth(){}

    public static Auth GetInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)            \\ADDED
           instance = new Auth();
        return instance;
    }
    public string Authorisation { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instantiate in the static method itself:

```
public class Auth
{
    private static Auth instance;

    private Auth(){}

    public static Auth GetInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new Auth();
        return instance;
    }
    public string Authorisation { get; set; }
}
```